# Creating plots with gridlines of equal width / thickness

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create plots with horizontal gridlines of equal thickness / width. My issue is that ggplot seems to use half-widths for the gridlines at the bottom and top of the panel. This appears to occur because the the gridline is vertically centered at the tick. As such, the top half of the top gridline is off the plot and the bottom half of the bottom gridline is off the plot. A minimal example is provided below:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "red", size = 5))
```

Is anyone aware of a solution?
(I am guessing that there are workarounds that involve the axis limits - but I am looking for a purer solution.)

Comment: what do you mean purer? adding `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.45, 1.55))` doesn't work for you?

Comment: I guess by "purer" I mean a solution that is part of ggplot rather than a "hack" (and I mean "hack" in the nicest sense of the word).

Comment: `+ ylim(c(0.495, 1.505))` is the simplest option. You see, the difficulty in automatic adjustment is that you should specify y scale limits in units of y, whereas line thickness is given in points. Conversion between these units is possible, but it's probably not worth it.